# I'm not sure on the correct SQL statement to use for inserting data from a MC access into a form on vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

There are many movies stored in the database, and there are ten picture boxes. I would want each picture box to show the film and its description once you click on it into another form. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eW83K.png)

I am not sure how to get this information from the database and put int into the new form. The movies displayed on the picture boxes will change every week, so will the data.  here is what i have tried already and it doesn't seem to work.
Could someone help me with this problem, much appreciated.

```
 Private Sub getmovieID()
    If DbConnect() Then
        Dim sqlcmd As New OleDbCommand
        With sqlcmd
            .Connection = cn
            .CommandText = "select MovieName from TblMovies MovieID = @MovieID"
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@MovieID", CurrentMovieID)


            Dim rs As OleDbDataReader = .ExecuteReader
            If rs.Read Then
                lbl_FilmName.Text = rs("MovieName")
                Txt_desc.Text = rs("MovieDescription")
                PB_mainIMG.Image = rs("MovieImage")
            End If


            rs.Close()
        End With

        cn.Close()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What is not working?  The SQL query not returning your data right?  Your form not being populated correctly?  What is not working?

Comment: the SQL statement not returning data, sorry

Comment: I see your variable you are adding to paramater for SQL:  CurrentMovieID  but in your vb code I dont see where it is being set?  Try debugging and stepping through code to see what your SQL statement is and what the value of your CurrentMovieID is then check the DB to see if it actually exists

Comment: yes the current movie id is the issue and doesn't appear to respond. In the database ive got movie id, movie name, decription and image.

Comment: the current movie id is set as a string in the main module and im not sure on how to get it working

Answer (score 0):

Your SQl command, when it return Data should have those 3 
 **"select MovieName,MovieDescription,MovieImage from TblMovies Where MovieID = @MovieID"**
and you need also a where clause

Comment: thanks a lot ill try that, also the current movie id doesn't seem to work so i think thats the other issue

Comment: you can try to use it  as a parameter when you call the sub